# Undefined property in PHP

Tags: php

I'm getting an error:

> Undefined property: stockdata::$status

in my code and I can't seem to find the issue.

The error occurs on line 101 on the first link of code. I am attempting to create a new instance of a class and use variables from that class.  From that I get the 'undefined property error'.

This is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body>
<nav class="navbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand">Testing</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link 420" href="#">Etc</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<div class="container">
<form action "" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="">
            <input type="user" class="form-control-sm" id="user" name="user" placeholder="username">    
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <input type="ticker" class="form-control-sm" id="ticker" name="ticker" placeholder="ticker">
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <input type="quantity" class="form-control-sm" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="quantity">
        </div>
    <!--
    <div class="btn-group">
        <label for="message" class=""></label>
        <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Asset Type</button>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">BTC/ALT</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">US-Market</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">FOREX</button>
  </div>
  -->
        <div class="">
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
            <form action "" method="post">
            <input type="ticker2" class="form-control-sm" id="ticker2" name="ticker2" placeholder="ticker">
            <input id="submit2" name="submit2" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>
</div>

</body>
```

And this is my PHP file:

```
<?php
include 'stockdata.php';

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "admin";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
/*
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
 else{
    */

/*
    $user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'user', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $quantity = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'user', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $ticker = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'user', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
*/


if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $ticker = $_POST['ticker'];


    $d4e = new stockdata;
    $d4e -> data($ticker,0);
    $d4e->status;
/*
    var_dump($dataforentry->stockarray)  <- This line is trash


    var_dump($d4e);

    */
    $sql = "INSERT INTO info (
    username, ticker, quantity)
    VALUES ('$user','$ticker','$quantity')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity=quantity+$quantity";

if ($conn->query($sql)==TRUE)
{
    echo "New record created successfully";
}
else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}

if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
    $ticker2 = $_POST['ticker2'];
    $guy = new stockdata;
    $guy -> data($ticker2,1);
}

/*
$guy = new stockdata;
$guy->data('AAPL');

*/
?>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>

<?php

/*
$ondemand = new SoapClient('http://ondemand.websol.barchart.com/service?wsdl');

$params = array(
    'symbols' => 'AAPL,GOOG',
    'fields' => 'fiftyTwoWkHigh,fiftyTwoWkHighDate,fiftyTwoWkLow,fiftyTwoWkLowDate',
    'mode' => 'I',
);

$result = $ondemand->getQuote($params);

echo $result;
*/
class stockdata{

public static function data($ticker,$output){

$get = file_get_contents('http://marketdata.websol.barchart.com/getQuote.json?key=85f03afeb0ebfb059b8e1812c74ff101&symbols=' . $ticker);
$result = json_decode($get,true);

$status = $result['status']['message'];
$exchange = $result['results'][0]['exchange'];
$symbol = $result['results'][0]['symbol'];
$lastprice = $result['results'][0]['lastPrice'];
$volume = $result['results'][0]['volume'];
$percentchange = $result['results'][0]['percentChange'];

$stockarray = array($status, $exchange, $symbol, $lastprice, $volume);
/*
class output extends stockdata{
public function data_out($ticker2){ 
}
These two functions should be separate.  Idea: Use $stockarray to pass the information.

*/

if($output==1){
    echo "Output is 1 (function with output) <br />";
    echo $status . "<br />";
    echo $exchange . " | " . $symbol . "<br />";
    echo "Last Price : " . $lastprice . "<br />";
    echo "Volume : " . $volume . "<br />";
    echo "Percent Change : " . $percentchange . "<br />";
    }
    else {
            echo "Output is 0 (function no output) <br />";}
    }
}
?>
```

I have searched and debugged this issue for a long time.  I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Post the relevant code here directly, as text.

Comment: And post the code for the class stockdata too (no pastebin please)

Comment: I can't figure out how to place a large code blocks on here, as not every line of my code has spaces before it.

Comment: Work out where approximately in the code the problem is and post that code. We don't need the whole kitchen sink :)

Comment: I included the code from the links into the question and formatted them properly. Furthermore I surrounded the code by some explanation.

Comment: Have you tried doing a var_dump on $result to check if it actually contains the data you're looking for?

Comment: Where is line 101?

Answer (score 0):

You  cannot access a function variable inside a class from the outside.

```
class stockdata{

    public function data($ticker,$output){
        ....
        $status = $result['status']['message']; // <--- this is not accessible.
    }
```

You will have to define it as a public property:

```
class stockdata{

    public $status; // definition.

    public function data($ticker,$output){
        ....
        $this->status = $result['status']['message']; // <-- Works!!
    }
```

Now you can access it.

```
$stock = new stockdata();
...
echo $stock->status;
```

Comment: You can't use $this->status with a function with static key! You will get an error like Using $this when not in object context ... AND with this $stock->status he will return the value of public $status not $this->status!

Answer (score 0):

Static properties cannot be accessed through the object using the arrow operator ->.

Static Keyword:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php